# UWSGI threads do not share data

Tags: python, multithreading, nginx, uwsgi

I have wsgi app that is run in emperor mode. The problem is that inside my wsgi app I start a thread, that does not share data with main process.

Consider an application like this:

```
[uwsgi]
module = myproject.myapp:app
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
master = true
processes = 1
socket = 127.0.0.1:8320
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
chdir = /etc/wsgiproject/
wsgi-file = /etc/wsgiproject/myproject/myapp.py
python_path = …
enable-threads = true
multithread = true
```

myapp file:

```
from myproject.app import create_app
import threading
app = create_app(port)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=port)
```

```
def create_app():
     app = Flask(__name__)
     counter = Counter(app)
     counter.number = 10
     threading.Thread(name='monitor', target=counter.monitor, daemon=True).start()
     return app
```

```
class Counter():

     def monitor(self):
          while(True):
              sleep(10)
              print(f'current value: self.number')

     def __init(self, app):
          self.app = app
          self.number = 0
          app.add_url_rule('/increaseNumber', view_func=self.increase_number, methods=['POST'])

     def increase_number(self):
          print(f'increased number: {self.number}')
          self.number+=1
```

The problem is that my daemon never updates number value, however it is updated when wsgi recieves request.

Expected output:

```
current value: 0
current value: 0
increased number: 1
current value: 1
increased number: 2
current value: 2
```

Actual output:

```
current value: 0
current value: 0
increased number: 1
current value: 0 <-- daemon has old value
increased number: 2
current value: 0
```

Comment: uWSGI threads and workers do not share memory.

Comment: @Antwane Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @Liz did you end up figuring out a solution to this?